# "The ScrollController is attached to multiple scroll views." I don't get this error

Tags: flutter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33_0ABjFJUU

I was watching above Decoding Flutter video.
According to the explanation of this video, if there are two ListViews on the same screen in the case of a mobile application, (both ListViews are primary == true,)
both will share one same PrimaryScrollController, so the following error should occur, shouldn't it?
"The ScrollController is attached to multiple scroll views."

However, when I run the sample code below, I get no errors at all
and both ListViews share the same ScrollController.

I feel like it's okay because no error occurs, but it seems that this behavior clearly contradicts the explanation in the video.

Am i missing something?

```
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp(),);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity,50.0,),
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: AppBar(

          ),
          onTap:(){

            PrimaryScrollController.of(context,)!.animateTo(
              0.0,
              curve:Curves.linear,
              duration:Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            );

          },
        ),
      ),
      body:Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width:150.0,
            child: ListView(
              primary: true,
              children:[
                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.red,
                ),

                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.green,
                ),

                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            width:150.0,
            child: ListView(
              //primary: false,
              children:[
                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.blue,
                ),

                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.brown,
                ),

                Container(
                  height:1350.0,
                  color:Colors.purple,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: They might have fixed the issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply.yes. Yes. 
The video was released yesterday, so if that's the case, I can't help but appreciate the speed of development.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the data. Can you tell your test device

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your reply. My device is iPhone SE2.